# How to check when all CompleteableFuture are done?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a `Stream<Item>` which I'm mapping to a `CompleteableFuture<ItemResult>`

What I'd like to do is to know when all the futures are completed.
One may suggest to:

1. collect all the futures to an array and use CompleteableFuture.allOf(). This is somewhat problematic since there could be hundreds of thousands of items
2. just continue with `forEach(CompleteableFuture::join)`. This is problematic too as calling forEach with join will just block the stream and it will be essentially a serial processing and not concurrent
3. Inject a poisoned item in the end of the stream. This could work but it's not that elegant in my view
4. check if the executor queue is empty - This is quite limiting because I might use more than one executor in the future. Also, the queue can be momentarily empty
5. Monitor the database instead and check the number of new items

I feel like all the suggested solutions aren't good enough.

What is the appropriate way to monitor the futures?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
another (vague) idea I had in mind is to use a counter and wait for it to go down to zero. But again, need to check that it's not a momentarily 0..

Comment: What's wrong with the first proposition? That's what should be used to _know when all the futures are completed_.

Comment: @sp00m, I think it does't scale well. What if I'd like to process 10M items? 100M items?

Comment: @yaseco Scaling badly in what sense? Do you worry about the size of the array or performance or something else?

Comment: @akuzminykh, yes. The size of the array

Comment: Maybe a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) could be another approach?

Comment: @sp00m, I don't know the number of items in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You want all your CF's to be done, but you also don't want to wait for all of them to be done since there may be too many? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Without knowing the number of items, I guess a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) could be useful then. How is your stream produced exactly? Are you in control of the `Item` and `ItemResult` classes?

Comment: @sp00m `Phaser` was the first thing that came into my mind, too. But its limit of 65535 is not suitable 100M items.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether `Phaser` is the right tool here, and if yes, whether it's better to have one root with multiple children or to chain them like I'm proposing below, so feel free to correct me.*

---

Here's one approach that uses [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).

A `Phaser` has a limited number of *parties*, so we need to create a new *child `Phaser`* if that limit is about to get reached:

```java
private Phaser register(Phaser phaser) {
    if (phaser.getRegisteredParties() < 65534) {
        // warning: side-effect,
        // conflicts with AtomicReference#updateAndGet recommendation,
        // might not fit well if the Stream is parallel:
        phaser.register();
        return phaser;
    } else {
        return new Phaser(phaser, 1);
    }
}
```

Register each `CompletableFuture` against that *`Phaser` chain*, and deregister once done:

```java
private void register(CompletableFuture<?> future, AtomicReference<Phaser> phaser) {
    Phaser registeredPhaser = phaser.updateAndGet(this::register);
    future
            .thenRun(registeredPhaser::arriveAndDeregister)
            .exceptionally(e -> {
                // log e?
                registeredPhaser.arriveAndDeregister();
                return null;
            });
}
```

Wait for all futures to be finished:

```java
private <T> void await(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    Phaser rootPhaser = new Phaser(1);
    AtomicReference<Phaser> phaser = new AtomicReference<>(rootPhaser);
    futures.forEach(future -> register(future, phaser));
    rootPhaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    rootPhaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```

Example:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);

// creating fake stream with 500,000 futures:
Stream<CompletableFuture<Integer>> stream = IntStream
        .rangeClosed(1, 500_000)
        .mapToObj(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                if (i % 50_000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + i);
                }
                return i;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }, executor));

// usage:
await(stream);
System.out.println("Done");
```

Outputs:

```
pool-1-thread-348: 50000
pool-1-thread-395: 100000
pool-1-thread-333: 150000
pool-1-thread-30: 200000
pool-1-thread-120: 250000
pool-1-thread-10: 300000
pool-1-thread-241: 350000
pool-1-thread-340: 400000
pool-1-thread-283: 450000
pool-1-thread-176: 500000
Done
```